# What age was Ripley by the end of Alien 3?

Tags: alien-franchise

Between *Alien* and *Aliens*, she was in hyper sleep for 57 years.
She was in hyper sleep again between *Aliens* and *Alien<sup>3</sup>* for some amount of time.

So how old was she by the finale of *Alien<sup>3</sup>*?

---

**EDIT**

recognizer and Xantec raise good points in the comments, I'll try and clarify.

There would be a date on Ripley's birth certificate and a date on her death certificate (at the end of *Alien<sup>3</sup>*).

**How many years apart were these two dates?**

Comment: I think there are three implicit parts to this question. First, How many years had passed since Ripley's birth? Second, how slowly does a person age in hypersleep, or is their aging completely static? And finally, as a consequence of those factors, how many years had her body aged, between being awake and in hypersleep?

Comment: Are you asking for her objective or subjective age?

Comment: @recognizer It's a bit more simple than that I'm afraid :). I've updated my question.

Comment: @recognizer it actually never occurred to me that her physical age could be different to her _chronological_ (?) age. She might have been alive for 200 years but only aged 150? Very interesting!

Comment: @Daft Since she does not physically age fifty-seven years between the first two films, she clearly is not aging naturally during that time. The parsimonious assumption is that hypersleep causes humans to either cease aging, or age at a very slow rate (perhaps one-eighth normal, given the change in Weaver's real-world age between Alien and Aliens).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's two questions here, Ripley's objective age (e.g. the difference between her birth-date and the date of the film) and her subjective age (e.g. how old she is taking into account time dilation and hypersleep). I'll address them both.

### Objective Age.

This is the easy one. Her DOB is given in a Special Edition DVD feature as January 7th, 2092. We know from the novelisation that Fiorina is only a few days travel from Gateway, which strongly implies that she was only in hypersleep for a few weeks between the ending of Aliens and the start of Alien³. Since we know that Aliens takes place in 2179 ([July, 2179](https://twitter.com/datesinmovies/status/609422020984619009) to be precise), that makes Ripley **87 years of age at the ending of Alien³**

### Subjective age

This one is a toughie because there's a few unknowns. In theory, she's subjectively 32 years of age *throughout* the events of Alien, Aliens *and* Alien³ (born 2092, shipped out 2124) but we don't really get much backstory to explain how much time she's spent in hypersleep since birth, nor do we know how much one ages during hypersleep. Certainly she *appears* to have aged, but that could just be down to stress.

Comment: I would add that it seems unlikely that the time span between the second movie and the third being similar to between the first two movies given that Bishop's designer was still alive and fairly young looking.